# Why does the following java statement compile successfully?

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors

I wonder why it makes sense to have an empty try block followed by catching specific exception? Any thoughts?

```
try {

} catch (Exception e) {
    // do nothing
}
```

Comment: Being legal and making sense are two different things; this is legal, but doesn't make much sense.

Comment: If you were catching Throwable instead, then I'm pretty a JLS conformant interpreter could throw ThreadDeath if the thread was killed between interpreting the start and end of the try block, though it is unlikely any would be implemented that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea is that unchecked exceptions can be thrown by any code, so if you're catching something which *can* catch an unchecked exception, the compiler doesn't check whether the code in the `try` block can throw anything. In the special case where there really is *no* code in the try block, this is inappropriate - but it keeps the language simpler, and it's only a problem in completely bogus code which I wouldn't expect to show up in any real codebase. I guess there are similar situations where you're only doing things with primitives etc, but it really is an edge case. Most try blocks *will* contain code which could theoreically throw an unchecked exception.

If you try to catch a *checked* exception type which isn't thrown in the `try` block, *then* the compiler will complain.

Comment: would it be more reasonable to validate the (empty) content case of the try block? I mean it would be really basic check...

Comment: @aviad: I don't think it's worth making the language specification cover pointless corner cases like this, personally. You shouldn't normally be catching Exception anyway, nor should you be creating empty try blocks.

Comment: +1, Jon Skeet is clear and concise as always. Do you think that the compiler may even "optimize" out this piece of code?

Comment: @Jon agreed. However, i just found this gem in some old code (the problematic statement that probably caused some bug was just commented out leaving the try block empty) and I was wondering why the compiler does not prevent such cases.

Answer (score 2):

runtime exceptions are not type-checked and can be unpredictably thrown

Comment: - not by the EMPTY try blocks

Answer (score 2):

Not everything that compiles should "make sense", as long as your code does not contain syntax and semantic errors it will compile and most likely even run.

The main idea is that every part of your code can potentially throw an exception. `Try Catch` blocks do not add an additional overhead to your compiled code and thus there is no problem using them even for any code.